# How to add new elements to an array without overwriting the first one?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to add new elements to an Array but it keeps overwriting it the first element, i'm not sure if i'm doing it correctly, but this is my code:

```
//name and age contains value from a NgModel 
this.data = [
    { "name": this.name, "age": this.age },
];

//Adds them to a new array 
this.nArray = [];
this.nArray.push(this.data);
```

Comment: Is this in its own method? Are you creating a new `[]` each time this method is called?. Hence only pushing one item into it each time.

Comment: Could you add more context?

Comment: @V.Sambor What i'm trying to do is keep adding new elements based on this.data(which contains name and age from an NgModel)

Comment: how do you 'keep adding'? In the code you have provided, you add only once. Show us the entire function at least.

Comment: @V.Sambor I think that's the problem how to add it more than once

Comment: @QuickAccount123 how have you tried to add more than once? could you share your tryings?

Answer (score 4):

Use concat when you want to merge two arrays.

```
const nArray = [];
const arr = nArray.concat(this.data);
```

You can now use the new merged array for your purpose

Answer (score 1):

`push` method is ok for you. It will add elements at the **end** of the array. If you have data already setted in your array, then remove `this.nArray = []` because this is creating a new empty array, deleting all previous data stored in `nArray` variable. In any case, if you want to add elements at the beginning try `unshift`: `this.nArray.unshift(this.data);`.

If you push `data` inside `nArray` you will get an array of array of objects. Maybe you are looking to add only the elements in `data` and not the whole array. Use `concat` method for that.

`this.nArray.push(this.nArray.concat(data));`

Or a shorten syntax using spread operator `...`:
`this.nArray.push(...data);`

**NOTE**:
I'd recommend you to use `const` for your array definition and remove the blank assignment of `[]` in `nArray`. Also, instead of using `concat`, use the spread operators with the `push` method.

Answer (score 1):

As it is, you are pushing an array to an empty array. So, there is nothing like *overriding* here. However, assuming `this.nArray` is filled with some elements already, you should use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for concatenating two arrays like:

```
this.nArray.push(...this.data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to add/insert an element into an array is to use the .splice() method.

With .splice() you can insert a new element at any given index, either overwriting what is currently in that index number, or inserting within, with no overwriting.

Example:

```
let secretMessage = [ 'Programming', 'is', 'not', 'about', 'what', 'you', 'get', 
'easily', 'the', 'first', 'time,', 'it', 'is', 'about', 'what', 'you', 'can',
'figure', 'out.', '-2015,', 'Chris', 'Pine,', 'Learn', 'to', 'Program' ]
```

read: *'Programming is not about what you get easily the first time, it is about what you can figure out. -2015, Chris Pine, Learn to Program'*

```
secretMessage.splice(6, 5, 'know,');

console.log(secretMessage.join(' '); //log array elements to console, but join them 
                                    //with a space (makes it more human legible)
```

read: *'Programming is not about what you know, it is about what you can figure out. -2015, Chris Pine, Learn to Program'*

In this example, at index (position) 6 (starting from 0) we replace the 5 elements from index 6 with the third argument - 'know,'.

If you wanted to insert an element without replacing another, use the same .splice() method but for the second argument, type 0.

Example:

```
let favDrink = ['I', 'like', 'milkshake.']

favDrink.splice(2, 0, 'banana'); //at index position 2, insert 'banana'. 
                                 //***Does not replace 'milkshake'***

console.log(favDrink.join(' ');
```

read: *'I like banana milkshake.'*

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 0):

You know what? You might be reinitializing your array every time.

Try something like this:

```js
// create your new array 
this.nArray = [];
// other code
// loop, etc
$.each(row, function(index, data) {
  this.data = [
    { "name": this.name, "age": this.age },
  ];
  // now add this element to your array:
  this.nArray.push(this.data);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the Object in the array...!
Write in this format

```
let data = [];

data[data.length] = {name:"Aarti",age:22}


data[data.length] = {name:"Saurav",age:23}

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Why would you use this over `Array.push`? I've never seen this before but I guess it would technically work